# go-swagger - Type struct not generated / found / imported

Tags: api, go, swagger, documentation, doc

I'm trying to use go-swagger to generate specs / docs of my Go service

```bash
swagger generate spec -o ./docs/swagger.json --scan-models
```

I'm able to generate basics infos + routes but i encountered an issue with my struct\

### *Here:* User struct is not imported

[docs/docs.go - github](https://github.com/CorentinTrt/erp-api/blob/main/service-users-data/docs/docs.go)

```golang
// Package classification Users' Data API
//
// Documentation for Users' Data API
//
//  Schemes: http
//  BasePath: /v1
//  Version: 0.1.0
//
//  Consumes:
//  - application/json
//
//  Produces:
//  - application/json
//
// swagger:meta
package classification

import (
    M "service-users-data/internals/database/models"
)

// A list of all Users
// swagger:response usersResponse
type productsResponseWrapper struct {
    // All current Users
    // in: body
    Body []M.User
}

// Generic error message returned as a string
// swagger:response errorResponse
type errorResponseWrapper struct {
    // Description of the error
    // in: body
    Body M.GenericError
}
```

*Swagger result:*
[docs/swagger.json - github](https://github.com/CorentinTrt/erp-api/blob/main/service-users-data/docs/swagger.json)

```json
  "responses": {
    "errorResponse": {
      "description": "Generic error message returned as a string"
    },
    "usersResponse": {
      "description": "A list of all Users",
      "schema": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {}
      }
    }
  }
```

### *Here:* User struct properties are not generated

[models/user.go - github](https://github.com/CorentinTrt/erp-api/blob/main/service-users-data/internals/database/models/user.go)

```golang
// User type define user object that will be stored in the DB
// swagger:model User
type User struct {
    // the firstname
    FirstName         string   `bson:"first_name" json:"firstName" validate:"required,max=50"`
    MiddleNames       []string `bson:"middle_names" json:"middleNames"`
    LastName          string   `bson:"last_name" json:"lastName" validate:"required,max=50"`
    Age               uint8    `bson:"age" json:"age" validate:"gte=16,lte=99"`
    Email             string   `bson:"email" json:"email" validate:"required,email"`
    Adress            adress   `bson:"adress" json:"adress"`
    Salary            salary   `bson:"salary" json:"salary"`
    Job               string   `bson:"job" json:"job" validate:"max=50"`
    JoStatus          string   `bson:"job_status" json:"jobStatus" validate:"omitempty,oneof=intern extern"`
    BeginingDate      int      `bson:"begining_date" json:"beginingDate"`
    NextInterviewDate int      `bson:"next_interview_date" json:"nextInterviewDate"`
    LastInterviewDate int      `bson:"last_interview_date" json:"lastInterViewDate"`
    ActivityStatus    string   `bson:"activity_status" json:"activityStatus" validate:"omitempty,oneof=active inactive"`
    CreatedOn         int      `bson:"created_on" json:"-"`
    UpdatedOn         int      `bson:"updated_on" json:"-"`
    DeletedOn         int      `bson:"deleted_on" json:"-"`
}

type adress struct {
    Number   uint16 `bson:"number" json:"number"`
    Street   string `bson:"street" json:"street"`
    City     string `bson:"city" json:"city"`
    Province string `bson:"province" json:"province"`
}

type salary struct {
    AmountYear int    `bson:"amount_year" json:"amountYear"`
    Bonus      string `bson:"bonus" json:"bonus"`
}
```

*Swagger result:* [docs/swagger.json - github](https://github.com/CorentinTrt/erp-api/blob/main/service-users-data/docs/swagger.json)

```json
  "definitions": {
    "User": {
      "description": "User type define user object that will be stored in the DB",
      "x-go-package": "service-users-data/internals/database/models"
    }
  },
```

### *Here:* User struct seems to not being used

```bash
$ swagger validate docs/swagger.json

2022/12/18 09:07:52
The swagger spec at "docs/swagger.json" is valid against swagger specification 2.0
2022/12/18 09:07:52
The swagger spec at "docs/swagger.json" showed up some valid but possibly unwanted constructs.
2022/12/18 09:07:52 See warnings below:
2022/12/18 09:07:52 - WARNING: definition "#/definitions/User" is not used anywhere
```

#### I would like to understand why my struct is not recognized / found / imported ?

Thank you for taking the time to read ;)

##### Edited:

### *Here:* Route definition

```golang
// Package api regroup all http related files
package api

import (
    "github.com/go-chi/chi"
)

// UserRoutes function attach each route to the right handler
func UserRoutes() *chi.Mux {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    userH := &UserH{}

    // swagger:route GET /users User listUsers
    // Return a list of all Users
    //
    // responses:
    //  200: usersResponse
    //  500: errorResponse
    //  503: errorResponse
    r.Get("/", userH.GetUsers)
    r.Post("/", userH.CreateUser)

    return r
}
```

Comment: can you show how you declared the route documentation ? https://github.com/yvasiyarov/swagger/wiki/Declarative-Comments-Format#3-api-operation 
I guess you forgot to declare the return type, which is why you'd get the warning

Comment: Sure, [_v1/routes.go - github](https://github.com/CorentinTrt/erp-api/blob/main/service-users-data/_v1/routes.go)

```golang
// UserRoutes function attach each route to the right handler
func UserRoutes() *chi.Mux {
 r := chi.NewRouter()

 userH := &UserH{}

 // swagger:route GET /users User listUsers
 // Return a list of all Users
 //
 // responses:
 // 200: usersResponse
 //  500: errorResponse
 //  503: errorResponse
 r.Get("/", userH.GetUsers)
 r.Post("/", userH.CreateUser)

 return r
}
```

Comment: I also put it at the bottom of my main message for a better formatting

Comment: I did not try to reproduce, but I guess it could be due to usersResponse being declared outside of api package. Personnaly I use swaggo, IMO the documentation is better and I manage to do most of what I want

Comment: The weird thing is the `userResponse` is imported as #ref. So, no problem with that it seems.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue but managed to resolve it.
The issue had to do with the way I had installed the swagger-cli.
On the [installation guide page](http://goswagger.io/install.html) I had chosen to install swagger using the guidance under the **Static binary** section.
I was running into the same issue in which the model/struct names would be part of the spec but none of the struct fields would be picked up.
I removed this installation of the cli and instead followed the guidance under **Installing from source**.
Next time I executed the
**swagger generate spec -o ./docs/swagger.json --scan-models**
command, the spec included all the struct fields and their annotations as I had originally expected

Comment: Thank you, i'll try this and keep you in touch!

Comment: I had this same issue. Installing from source fixed the issue.

Comment: this package relies on swagger-codegen which also needs to be installed on your machine in case anyone else comes across this issue (not mentioned in goswagger.io docs)

Comment: I had installed it using homebrew, but it got fixed after installing it from the source.